# Selecting one thing connected to several others in different MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Say I have an orders table consisting of id, customer_id, order_date and some other stuff. I also have an items table of things people can order consisting of item_id, item_name and price. And finally there is a table called c that connects order_id with item_id's.

What I would like to do is to get some data from the orders table on all orders containing certain items that I search for by name.

I could do something like this, but that is obviously a bad solution even with just two items, not to mention five or so. But I think it illustrates what I am looking for:

```
SELECT o.id, customer_id, order_date
FROM orders AS o, c AS c1, items AS i1, c AS c2, item AS i2
WHERE item_name = 'foo' AND c1.item_id = i1.id AND c1.order_id = o.id
AND item_name = 'bar' AND c2.item_id = i2.id AND c2.order_id = o.id
```

Could someone suggest a faster working solution? I assume this type of query is quite common, so I suppose there is at least one fast and clever solution. :)

One thing to take into consideration is that item_names aren't necessarily unique, which means that any solution that employs HAVING COUNT(...) > 1 will retrieve orders that contains 'foo' twice rather than at least one 'foo' and one 'bar'.

EDIT:

A couple of people have suggested that I use "WHERE item_name IN('foo','bar')" and then deleted their answers, but the query I am looking for should retrieve orders that contain both 'foo' and 'bar', not just either one of them. If I should construct my sample query above differently with explicit joins, I suppose it would look something like this:

```
SELECT o.id, customer_id, order_date
FROM orders AS o
INNER JOIN c AS c1
ON c1.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN items AS i1
ON i1.id = c1.item_id
INNER JOIN c AS c2
ON c2.order_id = o.id
INNER JOIN items AS i2
ON i2.id = c2.item_id
WHERE i1.item_name = 'foo' 
AND i2.item_name = 'bar'
GROUP BY o.id
```

(which takes quite some time to execute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rudy Limeback](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?1026404-Selecting-one-through-many-in-a-many-to-many-relationship) FTW:

```
SELECT o.id
FROM (SELECT c.order_id
    FROM items
    INNER JOIN c
    ON c.itemid = items.id
    WHERE items.item_name IN ('foo','bar')
    GROUP BY c.orderid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_name) = 2
  ) AS these
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.id = these.orderid
```